# what are the simplest ways to get a few GBs of data from ec2 linux instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a linux instance with several GBs of data.
What are simple ways of getting the data out to my local machine?

I wonder about S3, Cloudfront, scp, ftp, http etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say `scp`, closely followed by `rsync`. But if you have many small files (average below few dozen KiB) tarring it over ssh may be faster.